# How can I add custom text as a Toolbox in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

For example, I never mind the syntax for the jquery animate :

```
$('#book').animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
    left: '+=50',
    height: 'toggle'
  }, 5000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
```

and I'd like to store it into Visual Studio 2010. So, in the future, if I need to use it, just somethings like "Open ToolBox" -> Drag N Drop jquery animate text.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's actually a simpler way to do this.

Simply open the toolbox tab, click and drag the selected text to it
[image]

Once it's there, right click on it and rename it to what you like.

Then simply drag it to where-ever you like... 
[image]

(Note that my images are from VS2017, though this should also work on VS2010)

Comment: That's awesome! Thanks for the tip!

Comment: You saved so much of my time. Thanks :)

Comment: Still works in VS 2022!

Answer (score 1):

Okey, so first, open `Tools->Code Snippets Manager` (Ctrl-K, Ctrl-B).
You can review existing and add your own there.

Then, when editing file of given type (ex. HTML), two context options will be shown in right-click menu - `Insert Snippet` and `Surround With`. They're simple and intuitive to use, and googling will certainly help you.